# How to add a new type (.htc) in mongoose

Tags: mongoose-web-server

I am creating a CGI based application(using C) in mongoose server. That web application is using for hardware setting. Javascript, CSS, CGI,etc all things is working fine in my mongoose server. Here I want to use "**.htc**" files in CSS. So How it is possible in mongoose as same as in Apache. In Apache server we can use  "**AddType text/x-component .htc**", line in .htacces files to enable that support. Please let me how it is possible in Mongoose web server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set `extra_mime_types` option to `.htc=text/x-component`